# Difficulty in changing Dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change my `Dataframe` index to one of a current columns. My current dataframe looks like that:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2740 entries, 13 to 7110
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Nr       2740 non-null int64
dist     2740 non-null int64
place    2740 non-null object
group    2740 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 77.8+ KB
```

I want to set `place` as a index instead of `Nr`. I've checked already that values in `place` are unique. I used two approaches:

```
##1
df_new = df.set_index('place')
##2
df.set_index('place',inplace=True)
```

In both cases I am getting error: `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`

Looking on other answers on SO it looks like both should work. Can someone tell what I might be missing?

**EDIT 1:**

Whole error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback, not just the last line?

Comment: There is nothing between file line and typeerror?

Comment: @ayhan There is nothing more

Comment: My only guess is that while you were trying, you assigned a column to a dataframe called 'set_index'. Is it possible? http://i.imgur.com/IaEWHhh.png

Comment: @ayhan Well, not, because then it would also show up in `df.info()`. And as you can see it isn't there.

Comment: It can also be an attribute though.

Comment: See if you can set 'group' as index. and please show some of the data from "place"

Comment: @Merlin Good idea. You can also check by printing `df.set_index`

Comment: @ayhan I've just realized, that suggestion when I am using `set_index` looks different than I'd expect: http://imgur.com/eO4JAEk

Comment: Int64Index: 2740 entries, 13 to 7110  Do you anything to index --- 13-7110?

Comment: Yes those are pd.Series.__init__'s parameters. You've probably changed that method by mistake.

Comment: @ayhan I'm not sure how is this possible. I even tried changing df back to Dataframe, but using `pd.Series.to_frame` throws error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'`

Comment: Take successively smaller subsets of the DataFrame and try to `set_index` on those. If you still can't figure it out, post one of these subsets (a small one), so we can debug.

Comment: @ayhan Small set (I just used `head()`) works. It is really strange.

Comment: Can you try `print(type(df.set_index))`

Comment: @ayhan `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: Yeah you changed that method. You need to restart your kernel and start over I guess.

Comment: @ayhan Great, it works!